# Function that determines the validity of a binary tree by checking if there are loops

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have to complete the function

```
bool HasLoop(Node* root)
{    
}
```

which determines the validity of a binary tree by checking if it has any loops.

So an Example:

```
Valid:
  X1
 /  \
X4   X5
 \    \
  X3   X7

Invalid:
  X1
 /  \
X4   X5
 \  /  \
  X3   X7
```

My idea is to mark each node we traverse as visited, and if we come across a visited node again, we would know a loop exists. But most of the examples involve sets, and our class hasn't gone over that yet. How do I proceed?

EDIT: WHAT I CAME UP WITH:

```
struct Node
{
int data;
struct node *left; 
struct node *right;
bool visited = false;
};

bool HasLoop(Node* root)
{    
  if(root==nullptr)
return;

if(root->visited)
return true;

if(!root->visited)
{
    root->visited = true;
    hasALoop(root->left);
    hasALoop(root->right);
}
return false;


}
```

Comment: You could do simple tree-traversal (in any order you want) and set a flag for each node you visit. If the flag is already set then you have a "loop". Which is basically what you already say you could do. So why not try that?

Comment: Your idea is perfectly fine. Just because other people do it in a different way doesn't always mean your way is wrong.

Comment: Are you allowed to add another field. to the `Node` class? Otherwise even if you haven't gone over set yet, maybe you're allowed to use them anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how exactly would I set a flag for each node?

Comment: `bool visited;` in the node structure. First a traversal to reset the flag (`visited = false`). Then a second traversal to check it (`if (visited)`).

Comment: Does Node have a pointer to its own parent?  If so, that could lead to a non-recursive solution (perhaps).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, so  basically set node->visited for the left most nodes to true using recursion, and compare that to the visited of the rightmost nodes of the tree

Comment: What do you guys think? I traced this on paper, and it seemed to work.

Comment: A part from the messy indentation your code looks more or less OK to me. Does it work?

Comment: How would I do this without changing the standard node structure? I am allowed change the function to also pass in a vector.

Comment: @lostatall with a `std::set<Node*>`. Instead of setting `foo->visited` to true, insert `foo` into the set and instead of testing if `foo->visited` is true, check if `foo` is in the set.

Comment: How would I do this with standard vectors though. I also have a helper function that accepts a node and the vector and returns true if the node was found in the vector. Also the code I wrote doesn't work. I used an "empty" return statement in a bool function. Should I traverse through the tree iteratively?

Comment: @lostatall use the appropriate tools. `std::set` is what you need here. You can do it with a `std::vector` but it would be totally inefficient. Using an empty `return` in a non void function is wrong, it shouldn't even compile. Show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I'm actually not even supposed to find cycles. Apparently I'm only supposed to return true if a node loops back to itself or if a descendant of a node loops back to the node. So the example above would actually be valid, I'm not even sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by simple traversal of the tree, by using a `visited` flag attribute (basically a `bool` member variable).

First you have a traversal where you clear the `visited` flag. Then you do a second traversal checking if the `visited` flag have been set for the node. If it haven't then you set it, else you report a loop.

In pseudo-code it could look something like this:

```
void check_loop(tree_node* const root)
{
    if (root->visited)
    {
        // You have a loop, report it
    }
    else
    {
        root->visited = true;

        // Traverse to children
        if (root->left)
        {
            check_loop(root->left);
        }

        if (root->right)
        {
            check_loop(root->right);
        }
    }
}
```

In my example above, the sub-tree traversal stops once you found a loop.

This will check all nodes in the tree, interior as well as leaf nodes, and also catches complicated loops and not only direct ones as you show.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a similar function to the one I did in a recent contest

```
bool vis[100000] = {false};
int flag = 0;

void HasLoop(Node* root)
{    

if(root==NULL)
    return;

if(vis[root->data]==false)
    vis[root->data]=true;
else
    flag = 1; // This means it is already visited so set flag = 1


HasLoop(root->left);
HasLoop(root->right);

return;
}
```

Though this function works only if you don't have repeated data value in the tree. If you have it, then you can change structure of your tree so that every node has a unique id or index value and can check that in your vis array.