# How would I recursively traverse a tree that returns a bool

Tags: c++, tree

I have to complete a function that will return true if a "tree" has a node that points back to itself or if a node has descendants that point back to it. The tree has at most one of these loops for every call.

```
 struct Node
 {
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  int data;
 }


bool finder(Node* root, vector<Node*> cd) // helper
   {
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cd.size(); i++)
         if (cd[i] == root) return true;

     return false;
   }

 bool Looper(Node* root, vector<Node*> cd)//finder will be called to compare 
 the next node against the visited nodes.
 {
     

     returns false;

 }
```

I know I need to traverse the tree and mark each node by putting it in the vector, but I have no idea what traversal to do or how to do it. Any ideas?

Potential solution:

```
bool Looper(Node* root, vector<Node*> cd){
vector<Node*> visited;

if(finder(root,visited))
return true;

if(root==nullptr)
returnvalue = false;

if(!finder(root,visited))
{
visited.push_back(root);
return Looper(root->left,visited);
return Looper(root->right,visited);
        
}

return false;

}
```

Comment: Well you need to do a pre-order traversal. At each node mark it as being *visited* (is this what your `cd` vector is for? not sure) and if during your traversal you find an already visited node you know you have a loop. Then you can abort the traversal and return true, otherwise return false.

Comment: What is `Node`, `cd`, and `v`?

Comment: @john yes that is what my cd vector is for. How would I do a preorder traversal recursively in a bool function?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the definition of `Node`. But basically call the function recursively on the children of the node, if any of the recursive calls return true, then stop the recursion and return true, if all the recursive calls return false then return false.

Comment: interestingly, there is already a question with more information of what is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61315707/104774. This question is not a copy because it focuses more on 1 aspect of the problem, but it lacks some information.

Comment: @john I updated my code with a node structure.

Comment: @lostatall Well I think I've given you enough information to at least attempt a solution. If you get stuck please create a new question, and post your latest code.

Comment: @john I updated the question with a potential solution. I am having  trouble trying to figure out a way to traverse the trees. Empty return statements aren't legal in bool functions.

Comment: @lostatall I'm afraid I don't understand why you have two functions, `finder` and `Looper`. I'm not saying it's wrong but nothing in your problem description requires two functions. If all you're trying to do is detect cycles then the code can be much simpler than that. You only need one recursive boolean function to detect a cycle.

Comment: @lostatall I've added an answer with my understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @lostatall OK, looking at your code again it's closer than I realised (I'm a bit slow), your `finder` routine is the equivalent of the `std::find` function that I used, so that's good. The main issues are that you need to pass `visited` or `cd` (however you call it) by reference, and you definitely should not be declaring local vectors. The same vector should be shared by all the recusrive calls. Plus you call `finder` twice which is obviously ineffecicent. And finally that you didn't realise that you can just use `||` on the two recursive calls to get the correct return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Node
{
    // some other stuff...
    int id;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
};

bool finder(Node* root, Node* currentNode, std::vector<bool>& visited)
{
    visited[currentNode->id] = true;

    for (Node* node : currentNode->children)
        if (node == root)
        {
            std::cout << currentNode->id << '\n';
            return true;
        }
        else if (!visited[node->id] && finder(root, node, visited))
        {
            return true;
        }

    visited[currentNode->id] = false;

    return false;
}

bool Looper(Node* root, int n)
{
    std::vector<bool> visited(n, false);
    return finder(root, root, visited);
}

int main()
{
    Node n0{ 0 };
    Node n1{ 1 };
    Node n2{ 2 };
    Node n3{ 3 };

    n0.children.push_back(&n1);
    n0.children.push_back(&n2);

    n1.children.push_back(&n3);

    n3.children.push_back(&n0);

    if (Looper(&n0, 4))
        std::cout << "Found\n";
}
```

Output:

```
3
Found
```

Since you want a child node that points to a parent, your tree will contain cycles. So you have to keep track of which nodes you've visited. That's why I keep track of the visited nodes. also I would recommend using `std::vector` to represent the tree instead of using nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of your task, simply call `check_for_cycles` with your tree's root node and an empty vector to detect a cycle in your tree.

```
bool check_for_cycles(Node* node, vector<Node*>& visited)
{
    // null is a not a cycle
    if (node == nullptr)
        return false;
    // have we been here before? if so we have a cycle
    if (find(visited.begin(), visited.end(), node) != visited.end())
        return true;
    // mark this node as visited
    visited.push_back(node);
    // recursively check the sub trees
    return check_for_cycles(node->left, visited) || check_for_cycles(node->right, visited);
}
```

Note a vector isn't the best choice for visited because of the time cost of checking if a node is present. An unordered_map would be better, and so would having a field in the node itself that you could mark.

This is untested code.

Comment: I don't understand how the use of "or" will go through each node recursively.

Comment: @lostatall Well it won't necessarilly, but you don't want it to. If the left hand side of `||` returns true, then it won't check the right hand side. But that's exactly what you want. If you know the left side has a cycle, what's the point in checking the right hand side?

Comment: @lostatall Or are you just struggling with the concept of recursion in general? You wouldn't be the first beginner to not get recursion. Almost everyone struggles with it at first.